# How can I stop this third-party DLL from throwing Security Exceptions in my full trust web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I'm trying to use the [.NET port of Yahoo's YUI compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) in my web site, running on my local Windows 7 development machine.

The web application is running in Full Trust mode. Also, in my `web.config`, I have this set:

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
```

When I call this code, it throws a Security Exception

```
string output = "{someJavaScriptCode:true}"; 
output = JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(output);
```

The exception details:

> **Description:** The application
>   attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To
>   grant this application the required
>   permission please contact your system
>   administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> **Exception Details:**
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

Since this is my local development machine, I have full control over the server settings and have everything set to full trust as far as I can tell.

I've found [one possible solution on Google](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=212240), but I don't understand where the solution's code should go.

The solution was not very detailed and didn't provide any explanation as for why the solution worked.

Does anyone know a good solution to fix this? Preferably with complete code examples or a good explanation of what would be needed to make this work in my web app?

**edit** Here's the stack trace of the exception, in case it helps.

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Threading.Thread.set_CurrentCulture(CultureInfo value) +38
   Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor..ctor(String javaScript, Boolean isVerboseLogging, Encoding encoding, CultureInfo threadCulture, Boolean isEvalIgnored, ErrorReporter errorReporter) +196
   Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(String javaScript, Boolean isVerboseLogging, Boolean isObfuscateJavascript, Boolean preserveAllSemicolons, Boolean disableOptimizations, Int32 lineBreakPosition, Encoding encoding, CultureInfo threadCulture, Boolean isEvalIgnored) +119
   Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(String javaScript, Boolean isVerboseLogging, Boolean isObfuscateJavascript, Boolean preserveAllSemicolons, Boolean disableOptimizations, Int32 lineBreakPosition, Encoding encoding, CultureInfo threadCulture) +67
   Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(String javaScript, Boolean isVerboseLogging, Boolean isObfuscateJavascript, Boolean preserveAllSemicolons, Boolean disableOptimizations, Int32 lineBreakPosition) +112
   VideoSync.Js.Script.GetOutput(Boolean compress) in [REDACTED]\Script.ashx.cs:78
   VideoSync.Core.CombinerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContext c) in [REDACTED]\CombinerBase.cs:28
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +599
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171
```

Comment: The best (but probably impractical) solution would be to fix the JavaScriptCompressor class so that it doesn't change the thread's CurrentCulture. That appears to be a hack that was added (http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/workitem/3219) to stop numbers being rendered incorrectly in other locales; the right approach would be to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in every `ToString call.

Comment: @Bradley I decided to go with your solution. It turns out, there's only 2 places in the YUI code that were impacted by this bug so it was a really simple fix to change. Once I changed it, I removed all of the calls to set the culture and everything worked. I'm still curious to find out what it would take to allow the stock YUI code to run without modification.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `PermissionSet` Attribute to your method that tries to call the `JavaScriptCompressor.Compress` method.

So it would look like this:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
void CompressSomething()
{
    // ...

    var result = JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(output);

    // ...
}
```

This basically tells the CLR to assume that the code in this method has already passed any required security check, so it should allow it to make inner calls.

You should be aware that this code may have some security consequences, and it's recommended to read in more depth about .NET's Code Access Security. Here's a useful link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0(v=vs.71).aspx

**EDIT - Another suggestion, having seen the stack trace:**

The problem seems to be that setting the current `CultureInfo` requires `SecurityPermission` on the current stack.

Maybe try the following:

```
var cas = new SecurityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
try
{
    cas.Assert();

    // ...
    var result = JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(output);
    // ...
}
finally
{
    CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
}
```

If it doesn't work, try to play with the parameter you send to the `SecurityPermission` constructor. Maybe some bits are needed on a `SecurityPermissionsFlag` enum you can send to it.

Comment: I added `[[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)] ]` to the method that calls `Compress`, and I got the same exception.

Comment: In that case, can you post the exception stack trace? Maybe it's something else. Also: did you try adding the Assembly attributes from the link you mentioned, as well? Or only the method attribute?

Comment: @Ran I also added the assembly attributes from the link I mentioned. I've updated my answer to include the stack trace.

Comment: I just tried using `SecurityPermission`, both with `PermissionState.Unrestricted` and `SecurityPermissionFlag.AllFlags`. Neither worked. Any idea why I should be getting security exceptions at all in a full trust environment to begin with?

Comment: The code in `set_CurrentCulture` does a `Demand`, so the CLR has to do a stack walk to ensure security. Maybe something is not configured right in your project and it doesn't really have full trust. BTW: Do you get the same exception if you just try to change the current `CultureInfo` in the current thread? If you do, this would eliminate problems related to the YUI assembly.

Comment: I can set the current culture just fine within the same method without any kinds of assertions. It only breaks within the YUI assembly.